# Airflow Cloud Build Operator not executing python function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, yaml, airflow, google-cloud-build

I can’t get the second arg statement to execute:

```
"python", "-c", "from main import foo;print(foo('hello'))"
```

I’m triggering a Cloud Build using the Airflow operator CloudBuildCreateBuildOperator.
Both the triggering DAG and Cloud Build return successful.

The first arg to install the requirements.txt file appears to work based on the Cloud Build returned log message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.2->gcsfs>=0.6.2
```

My function is using the gcsfs package. The function I have used in the question is just for demonstration.

Before using Airflow I had this working in a yaml file.
Tried a number of different ways of stating the argument, such as:

```
"args":["-c","pip install -V -r requirements.txt; python -c from main import foo;print(foo('hello'))"]
```

But now going round in circles.

I would greatly appreciate any help to get that args statement working.

This is the CloudBuildCreateBuildOperator from the DAG:

```
create_build_from_storage_body = {
  "source": {
    "repoSource": {
      "projectId": "dev-6767",
      "repoName": "bq-pipeline",
      "branchName": "master",
    }
  },
  "steps": [{
    "name": "docker.io/library/python:3.7",
    "entrypoint": "/bin/bash",
    "args": ["-c", "pip install -V -r requirements.txt",
      "python", "-c", "from main import foo;print(foo('hello'))"
    ],
  }],
}
```

Comment: Hi @BPsinoza could you please give it a try following the pattern used in this example [here](https://1904labs.com/2020/08/14/how-to-test-and-deploy-airflow-dags-to-cloud-composer/)? As shown, it seems that you would need to split your args in multiple `args` for better execution.

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel thanks for the link. The example used the && which allows me to chain the commands. This now works:  "args":[ "-c","pip install -r requirements.txt && python main.py"]

Comment: Hi @BSpnioza glad to hear it helped you! Do you mind if I post my comment - with more information - as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel, please do, happy to accept.

Comment: I have posted. Thanks @BSpinoza !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this example [here](https://1904labs.com/2020/08/14/how-to-test-and-deploy-airflow-dags-to-cloud-composer/) the best way to chain commands and send multiple `args` with Python would be with adding an `&&` between them.

Below is an example of how to send the args using this format, for chain of commands.

```
#testing1
steps:
- name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.7'
  id: Test
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - -c
  - 'pip install pytest && pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest test/*_test.py'
- name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
```

This way, it's possible use more than one argument within the Cloud Build trigger.